# Leet code: house robber, use recursive + memo

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

I am looking at this [discussion](https://leetcode.com/problems/house-robber/discuss/156523/From-good-to-great.-How-to-approach-most-of-DP-problems.)

**Step 4**

Iterative + memo (bottom-up)

```
public int rob(int[] nums) {
    if (nums.length == 0) return 0;
    int[] memo = new int[nums.length + 1];
    memo[0] = 0;
    memo[1] = nums[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < nums.length; i++) {
        int val = nums[i];
        memo[i+1] = Math.max(memo[i], memo[i-1] + val);
    }
    return memo[nums.length];
}
```

Questions:

- Does `memo[i]` mean robbing the non-current house?
- Does `memo[i-1] + val` mean robbing the current house?
- I am reading step 3 and find this: `memo[i] = Math.max(rob(nums, i - 2) + nums[i], rob(nums, i - 1));`. I am a bit confused with `memo[i+1] = Math.max(memo[i], memo[i-1] + val);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`memo` isn't storing any particular decision per se. Rather, it's storing the best solution up to the `i`th element, the heart of a [dynamic program](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming). Since it is being assigned to `memo[i+1]`, the choice between `memo[i]` and `memo[i-1] + val` can be thought of as *either the best up to the `(i-1)`th house (so without robbing the `i`th), or, if we were to rob it, then we have to skip a house so let's add that robbery to the best up to the `(i-2)`th house*. (Notice that `memo[i+1]` is the best up to the `i`th house, so `memo[i-1]` is the best up to the `(i-2)`th house. This is for the convenience of processing the first house, which is an edge case.)

That should also give you a hint as to how to understand the top-down recursion - again, if we were to choose to rob, we need to add that to the best solution that skips over the previous house.